# Collect feedback via Email (Outlook Client)

Tags: c#, ms-office, ms-access-2010, outlook-2010

I want to collect weekly feedback from my peers about their workload (numbers 0-9 for every workday). At the moment, they just send me a blank email with the subject line "5,8,6,2,9" and I have to put this information manually into a spreadsheet. This is too much work so I would like to automate the process. 
Outlook in combination with Access has the nice feature to create emails and process the responses automatically: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/collect-data-by-using-e-mail-messages-HA010015427.aspx
Unfortunately, this does not seem to support "who" (put the sender of the response into the database) sent the email.

This is why I was thinking about creating a small add-in to read the subject of incomming emails and extract the "3,9,..." automatically and put it to a Access database.

Only question if this is the right approach for this task or if I am overdoing it.

Please note: External Websites (like surveymonkey are not an option).

Comment: Is making an _internal_ web site an option?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That would only be the last resort. Email is much easier for the users and offers a lot of functionality outright (any client, fast, offline capable) for my "simple" task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it's one of the right approachs. It's very easy to write an Outlook Add-In which iterates through all mails with a specific subject and saves Sender and Mail-Body to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In the end, I implemented it in VBA because it did not require anything to install and was enough for our simple requirement.